# How Can I Chance or Set the Access Modifier in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, access-modifiers, xamarin.forms

I have to access user control in different view. But I get the inaccessible due to control's protection level error. I searched quite for a long time but I can't find anything. Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information. Please add some code, etc

Comment: In my xamarin forms project, I created a Main Page. This page has a frame and the other user controls. I want to place all of the another page to  the frame.

I mean the Main Page will show during the application lifetime and all of the navigation between pages become over this main page's frame. That is what I want to do exactly. So I want to access Main Page's user controls from other pages which in the frame content. 
I draw something like this http://prntscr.com/8hj7ia

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions I can think of:

- Hard-way: Create a custom MultiPage with custom renderer for every platform (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MultiPage%601/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)
- Make a custom ContentView with all you layout elements and bindable properties and add it to all you pages (and set the correct bindings). Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610859/5064986

Answer (score 0):

(I think) I had a similar situation. I found that a ListView was inaccessible due to protection level in the code behind to the xaml.  I added this to the ListView element.

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/field-modifiers) in docs.