# Binding Multiple Custom Property in a Custom View using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As mentioned in the [Binding a Custom View In Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606513/binding-a-custom-view-in-xamarin-forms) we have defined the Custom Binding properties for Custom view.

When we have a single Custom property , the custom view fires up the property (get,set) and assigns the vales. But when we have multiple Custom Properties the Properties(get,set) are not fired up.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

**Sample Source Code for Reference:**

Custom View (StackLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.UCCustomTab"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource stklTabLayoutStyle}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout x:Name="stkl_Tab1" Style="{StaticResource StklTabStyle}">
            <Image x:Name="iv_Tab1"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="stkl_Tab2" Style="{StaticResource StklTabStyle}">
            <Image x:Name="iv_Tab2"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="stkl_Tab3" Style="{StaticResource StklTabStyle}">
            <Image x:Name="iv_Tab3"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="stkl_Tab4" Style="{StaticResource StklTabStyle}">
            <Image x:Name="iv_Tab4"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Custom View (Stack Layout) Xaml.cs:**

```
  public partial class UCCustomTab : StackLayout
{
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public UCCustomTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsTab1VisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<UCCustomTab, bool>(w => w.IsTab1Visible, default(bool));

    public bool IsTab1Visible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTab1VisibleProperty); } set { SetValue(IsTab1VisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsTab2VisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<UCCustomTab, bool>(w => w.IsTab2Visible, default(bool));

    public bool IsTab2Visible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTab2VisibleProperty); } set { SetValue(IsTab2VisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsTab3VisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<UCCustomTab, bool>(w => w.IsTab3Visible, default(bool));

    public bool IsTab3Visible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTab3VisibleProperty); } set { SetValue(IsTab3VisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsTab4VisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<UCCustomTab, bool>(w => w.IsTab4Visible, default(bool));

    public bool IsTab4Visible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTab4VisibleProperty); } set { SetValue(IsTab4VisibleProperty, value);}
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == IsTab1VisibleProperty.PropertyName)
            stkl_Tab1.IsVisible = IsTab1Visible;
        if (propertyName == IsTab2VisibleProperty.PropertyName)
            stkl_Tab2.IsVisible = IsTab2Visible;
       if (propertyName == IsTab3VisibleProperty.PropertyName)
            stkl_Tab3.IsVisible = IsTab3Visible;
       if (propertyName == IsTab4VisibleProperty.PropertyName)
            stkl_Tab4.IsVisible = IsTab4Visible;
    }                               
}
```

Content Page:

```
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="#E9E9E9"
                  Grid.Row="0">
      <controls:UCCustomTab x:Name="RecordRequestTab"                              
                          IsTab1Visible="{Binding ll_Tab_UserDetailVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsTab2Visible="{Binding ll_Tab_TeamDetailVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsTab3Visible="{Binding ll_Tab_CallDetailVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsTab4Visible="{Binding ll_Tab_AlertDetailVisible,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </controls:UCCustomTab>
      <!--TabSelectedbgColor="#FF8989" TabDeSelectedbgColor="#E9E9E9"
      Tab1SelectedImage="tab_hd_user.png" Tab1DeselectedImage="tab_hd_user_U.png" Tab1Image="tab_hd_user.png"
      Tab2SelectedImage="tab_hd_team.png" Tab2DeselectedImage="tab_hd_team_U.png" Tab2Image="tab_hd_team_U.png"
      Tab3SelectedImage="tab_hd_call.png" Tab3DeselectedImage="tab_hd_call_U.png" Tab3Image="tab_hd_call_U.png"
      Tab4SelectedImage="tab_hd_alert.png" Tab4DeselectedImage="tab_hd_alert_U.png" Tab4Image="tab_hd_alert_U.png"-->
```

But when we set the "ll_Tab_CallDetailVisible,ll_Tab_TeamDetailVisible , ll_Tab_UserDetailVisible",ll_Tab_AlertDetailVisible" properties to false randomly  everything shows rather than hiding.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Kathirvelu M

Comment: As I understood, when you set some property to `true`, you don't set previous property to `false`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No  @EgorGromadskiy, I am setting all the properties and its values. For Ex: ll_Tab_CallDetailVisible = true,ll_Tab_TeamDetailVisible =false, ll_Tab_UserDetailVisible=true,ll_Tab_AlertDetailVisible=false.