# Xamarin.Forms binding to a binding property or something

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PassSystem.Controls;assembly=PassSystem"
             x:Class="PassSystem.Views.CreatePassPage"
             Title="Оформление пропуска">
    <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <FlexLayout Direction="Column" BackgroundColor="White">
                <controls:ActionOption Title="Название" Value="1" LeftMargin="18">
                </controls:ActionOption>
            </FlexLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

and i have contentview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PassSystem.Controls;assembly=PassSystem"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:PassSystem.Effects;assembly=PassSystem"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PassSystem"
             x:Class="PassSystem.Controls.ActionOption">
    <FlexLayout x:Name="MainLayout" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Center" AlignContent="Center" AlignItems="Center" HeightRequest="52"
                effects:ClickableEffect.ClickCommand="!!"
                effects:ClickableEffect.CancelCommand="{Binding UpCommand}"
                effects:ClickableEffect.UpCommand="{Binding UpCommand}"
                effects:ClickableEffect.DownCommand="{Binding DownCommand}">

        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
               TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryTextColor}"
               FontSize="15"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               FlexLayout.Grow="1"
               Margin="{Binding TitleMargin, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </Label>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="16" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,8,0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="12" TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryTextColor}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <controls:IconView Source="forward" HeightRequest="14" WidthRequest="14" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource AdditionalTextColor}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <FlexLayout.Effects>
            <effects:ClickableEffect />
        </FlexLayout.Effects>
    </FlexLayout>
</ContentView>
```

.cs file

```
public partial class ActionOption : ContentView
    {
        public ActionOption()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get => _title;
            set
            {
                if(value == _title) return;
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _value;
        public string Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                if (value == _value) return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Thickness TitleMargin => new Thickness(_leftMargin, 0, 6, 0);

        private double _leftMargin;
        public double LeftMargin
        {
            get => _leftMargin;
            set
            {
                if (Math.Abs(value - _leftMargin) < 0.01d) return;
                _leftMargin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TitleMargin));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _clicked;
        public ICommand Clicked
        {
            get => _clicked;
            set
            {
                if (value == _clicked) return;
                _clicked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand UpCommand => new Command(() => MainLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fff"));
        public ICommand DownCommand => new Command(() => MainLayout.BackgroundColor = (Color)((App)Application.Current).Resources["HighlightingColor"]);
    }
```

And I need to bind the ClickableEffect.ClickCommand from the page. I.e.

```
<controls:ActionOption Title="TitleHere" Value="1" LeftMargin="18" Clicked="{Binding ClickedCommand}">
</controls:ActionOption>
```

And in control

```
`effects:ClickableEffect.ClickCommand="{Binding ClickCommand (FromPage)}"`
```

Additional information. ClickableEffect

```
{
        public ClickableEffect() : base("PassSystem.ClickableEffect")
        {
        }

        #region Click

        public static readonly BindableProperty ClickCommandProperty = BindableProperty
            .CreateAttached("ClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ClickableEffect), (object)null);

        public static ICommand GetClickCommand(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (ICommand)view.GetValue(ClickCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetClickCommand(BindableObject view, ICommand value)
        {
            view.SetValue(ClickCommandProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty ClickCommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty
            .CreateAttached("ClickCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(ClickableEffect), (object)null);

        public static object GetClickCommandParameter(BindableObject view)
        {
            return view.GetValue(ClickCommandParameterProperty);
        }

        public static void SetClickCommandParameter(BindableObject view, object value)
        {
            view.SetValue(ClickCommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Implementation of Clickable Effect on Android:

```
public class ClickableListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
    {
        private Element Element { get; }
        private View View { get; }

        public ClickableListener(Element element, View view)
        {
            Element = element;
            View = view;
        }

        ...

        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            Tap();
        }

        private void Tap()
        {
            var command = ClickableEffect.GetClickCommand(Element);
            var parameter = ClickableEffect.GetClickCommandParameter(Element);
            command?.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("PassSystem")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidClickableEffect), "ClickableEffect")]
namespace PassSystem.Droid.Native.Effects
{
    public class AndroidClickableEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private bool _attached;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            //because an effect can be detached immediately after attached (happens in listview), only attach the handler one time.
            if(!_attached)
            {
                var control = Control ?? Container;

                var listener = new ClickableListener(Element, control);
                control.SetOnClickListener(listener);
                ...
                _attached = true;
            }
        }
}
```

How to implement this? Thank you.
P.S. It's hard for me to explain and I hope you understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired behaviour:

1. `ClickCommand` have to be an attached property of a `ClickableEffect`. More information can be found in the official doc: [Passing Effect Parameters as Attached Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties).
2. Since you have a `ContentView` in between the effect and the page, you have to make sure that `BindindContext` of the `ContentView` is set correctly. I am afraid that you will have to define a `ClickCommand` bindable property on the `ContentView` level and bind it to the effect's command. So: `Page.BindingContext.ClickCommand` => `ContentView.ClickCommand` => `ClickableEffect.ClickCommand` (where => is binding).

Which basically raise a question - why do you need an effect?

Comment: 1. Yes, I have it.
2. I tried to implement it. On the page in the ViewModel, I created an ICommand "ClickCommand", and in ContentView created "ClickCommand" too. But it did not work for me. Most likely I somehow incorrectly connected the data. Because with the binding of ContentView -> СlickbleEffect it works.

I need this effect to recognize gestures.

Comment: 2. Most probably you didn’t set the BindingContext of the ContentView to self.

Comment: No, I wrote BindingContext = this.

Comment: Don't do it on the ContentView level but on the button that is using this effect.

Comment: Can be more? The ContentView itself is my button.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code behind of the `controls:ActionOption` and the effect. The `controls:ActionOption` BindingContext should not be set (defaults to the page it is on), however the BindingContext of the child control of `controls:ActionOption` that is using the effect with the command should be set to `this` (it's parent `controls:ActionOption`). It might sound confusing, but try to visualise the binding and you will understand it better.

Comment: ok, I will try to visualise the binding. And maybe it will help me [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606513/binding-a-custom-view-in-xamarin-forms